# "Unable to Download App" on iOS8

Tags: ios, deployment, ios8, ios-provisioning

I have built an app on IOS7.1 and have signed it using an enterprise distribution license. I have placed this IPA and generated plist in a folder on a windows server. This folder has permissions so that only authorized people can install the app. This worked great till iOS8 was released. Now when a user tries to install the app, he/she is presented with "Unable to Download App: appName could not be downloaded at this time" message. On dismissing the alert, a black icon with the title "waiting..." is displayed.

I notice that with XCode 6, it no longer has an option to generate the plist for IPA sharing so I used the plist from my iOS7.1 project (which works on iOS7.1 devices).

**What is interesting/strange is the users are able to install the app on an iOS8 device if I remove the security on the folder which houses the IPA file, the icon images and the plist.**

Do I have to do something different in iOS8 to achieve this?

Cheers

Comment: Have you tried using TestFlight ? We're currently using that to upload our enterprise IPA. You can specify which testers can install each version of the app too. (https://www.testflightapp.com/)

Comment: Zhang, due to security reasons we require the IPA file to be housed on our servers.